# <hr/> не отображается в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            <h1>Все записи:</h1><hr />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="float-right" src="" alt="img" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
```

Самый последний `<hr/>` в конце не отображается, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Мб, это из-за незакрытых двух последних `div`'ов?

Comment: В отладчике браузера надо посмотреть, какой стиль к нему применяется. Возможно его перекрывает какой-то другой стиль

Comment: дело в том, что на него действуют те же стили, что и на первый <hr/>